# Obj iteration dynamically - javascript

Tags: javascript, json, iteration

I have a json object, which needs to be iterated, I can make use of iteration as a function but wanted to see if there is a simpler way to do so.
Object is as shown below:

```
obj = [
  {
    name: 'FolderA',
    child: [
      {
        name: 'FolderB',
        child: [
           {
            name: 'FolderC0',
            child: [],
          },
          {
            name: 'FolderC1',
            child: [],
          }
         ]
       }
   ],
 },
 {
    name: 'FolderM'
    child: []
 }
]
```

On some event I get level, like

```
level = "0-0-1"
```

Which I split to get [0, 0, 1]
Meaning, 0th index, nested 0th index and further nested 1st index, which I get like:

```
obj[0][0][1],
```

But since nested structure depth is unknown I want the above to be generated dynamically, something like this:

```
obj + [0] + .children[0] + .children[1],
```

Not sure if this can be done, but if there is, please let me know, else I will have to use recursive function. Thanks

Comment: You should use recursion for iteration nested objects.

Comment: Side note: JSON is a string representation of an object. What you have is *the object itself*, not its *string representation*. So please just say "object" instead of "json object"; and don't tag it with `json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string and then use reduce on the array of indexes:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'FolderA',
    child: [
      {
        name: 'FolderB',
        child: [
          {
            name: 'FolderC0',
            child: [],
          },
          {
            name: 'FolderC1',
            child: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'FolderM',
    child: [],
  },
];
const getObject = (arr, path) =>
  path
    .split('-')
    .reduce((result, key) => result.child[key], {
      child: arr,
    });

console.log(getObject(arr, '0-0-1'));
```

Comment: Charm!! Thanks.

Comment: Can you give me link of a resource to learn advance javascript?

Comment: @MichaelPhilips The [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) is useful when working with array (reduce is in there as well). A good read is the YDKJS series but [this one](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/es6%20%26%20beyond) will get you familiar with ES6 syntax.